# How to remove arbitrary subtitles formats from mkv with a shell loop

Tags: files, scripting, video, video-subtitles

I made this script to remove ALL subs from all mkv files in a given path. It works ok. But now I want to only remove PGS subtitles and keep all SRT files, no matter the language.

```
for file in "$@"*mkv; do
    mkvmerge -o "${file%.mkv}".nosubs.mkv --no-subtitles "$file"
done
```

Bonus : How to keep all SRT files of a arbitrary language.

Comment: The `--subtitle-tracks` only supports specific track IDs or language codes, so you'll probably have to get the list of track IDs, process them and then remove those matching the specific format.

Comment: Aren't language codes enough?

Comment: What if you have both pgs and srt subtitles for a given language?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-I` option in `mkvmerge` has been removed and replaced with `-J` which outputs JSON.
Here's [lumato's script](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/411555/167438) adapted to be used with (requires `jq` to be installed see [this link](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/) for installation instructions by OS)

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
# If no directory is given, work in local dir
if [ -d "$1" ] || [ -f "$1" ]; then
  DIR="$1"
else
  echo "No target path given, using working directory '$(pwd)'"
  DIR="." 
fi

# Get all the MKV files in this dir and its subdirs
find "$DIR" -type f -name '*.mkv' | while read filename
do
    subs=$(mkvmerge -J "$filename" | jq -r '.tracks[] | select(.type=="subtitles") | select(.properties.language=="eng").id' | sed 'N;s/\n/,/') 
    if [[ -n $subs ]]
    then
         subs="-s $subs"
    else
        subs=-S
    fi
    echo -e "Extracting tracks \e[1m\e[34m${subs#* }\e[0m from \e[1m\e[34m${filename}\e[0m..."
    mkvmerge $subs -o "${filename%.mkv}".eng-srt-only.mkv "$filename" > /dev/null 2>&1
done
```

Comment: you should use -d to check that $1 is a directory at all

Answer (score 3):

Parse the output of `mkvmerge -I` to get the desired track IDs, and pass the result as a comma-separated list with the `--subtitle-tracks` (`-s`) option.

To select only SRT subtitles using `sed`:

```
for file in "$@"*.mkv; do
    subs=$(mkvmerge -I "$file" | sed -ne '/^Track ID [0-9]*: subtitles (SubRip\/SRT).*/ { s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\):.*/\1/;H }; $ { g;s/[^0-9]/,/g;s/^,//;p }')
    if [[ -n $subs ]]; then subs="-s $subs"; else subs=-S; fi
    mkvmerge $subs -o "${file%.mkv}".srt-only.mkv "$file"
done
```

Similarly, to select only English SRT:

```
for file in "$@"*.mkv; do
    subs=$(mkvmerge -I "$file" | sed -ne '/^Track ID [0-9]*: subtitles (SubRip\/SRT).* language:eng.*/ { s/^[^0-9]*\([0-9]*\):.*/\1/;H }; $ { g;s/[^0-9]/,/g;s/^,//;p }')
    if [[ -n $subs ]]; then subs="-s $subs"; else subs=-S; fi
    mkvmerge $subs -o "${file%.mkv}".eng-srt-only.mkv "$file"
done
```

Change `language:eng` to select another language.

Comment: Dude, you are a hero! Look at those sed and regex... you'll help thousands of people. Thanks so much

Comment: To make it a single-file script, replace the `for` line with `file=$1` and drop the `done` line. For the type parameter, you could replace `SubRip\/SRT` with, say, `'"$(sed -e 's/[[*.\/\\]/\\&/g' <<< "$2")"'` (this is like `'"$2"'` but escapes [characters special to `sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#BRE-syntax)). For the language parameter, do the same with `eng` and `$3` (and possibly just using `'"$3"'` since the language code is just three lowercase letters and those aren't special to `sed`).

Comment: `mkvmerge` doesn't seem to support in-place editing. You could delete the input after processing (e.g. `&& rm -- "$file"` after the `mkvmerge` command) or write a temporary file and rename it over the original (e.g. `mkvmerge $subs -o "$file.$$.mkv" && mv -- "$file.$$.mkv" "$file"`), which would reduce the free disk space requirement to roughly the size of the largest file.

Comment: `mkvmerge -I` has been removed and replaced with `-J` which outputs a JSON
. See my other comment to see an adapted script.